# When using Pandas DataFrame.sort(), can I make it actually renumber the rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I am always surprised by this:

```
> data = DataFrame({'x':[1, 2], 'y':[2, 1]})
> data = data.sort('y')
> data
   x  y
1  2  1
0  1  2

> data['x'][0]
1
```

Is there a way I can cause the indices to be reassigned to fit the new ordering?

Comment: This wouldn't make sense if the indices are timestamps for example. You can reassign the index property if you need to.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For my part, I'm glad that sort doesn't throw away the index information.  If it did, there wouldn't be much point to having an index in the first place, as opposed to another column.

If you want to reset the index to a range, you could:

```
>>> data
   x  y
1  2  1
0  1  2
>>> data.reset_index(drop=True)
   x  y
0  2  1
1  1  2
```

Where you could reassign or use `inplace=True` as you liked. If instead the real issue is that you want to access by position independent of index, you could use `iloc`:

```
>>> data['x']
1    2
0    1
Name: x, dtype: int64
>>> data['x'][0]
1
>>> data['x'].iloc[0]
2
```